# Как вызвать окно "Поделиться" в телеграм боте на python

Tags: python, бот, telegram

Хочу реализовать собственную кнопку "поделиться", которая работает так же, как встроенная в телеграмме. К сути: есть бот, который даёт определенный результат(картинка+текст), я хочу вывести под ним кнопку "Поделиться", которая позволит юзеру выбрать получателя и отправить этот текст+картинку. Т.е., аналог обычной телеграмовской кнопки, но в своём виде.
Всё, что нашел - это switch_inline_query, но оно отправляет только текст, еще и никнейм бота приплетает. Еще вариант: через https://telegram.me/share/url?url=, но т.к. у меня переписка с ботом, то мне не на что ссылаться для данного метода. Больше вариантов я не нашел, всё облазил, голову сломал, может есть подходящий способ?